# Create JSON from dynamic HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Here is my fiddle: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/vdtx3Lb8/)

I want my JSON to be as below on click of "Save Actions" and when the category is "SMS". I'm not able to achieve this.

Also, the form fields change on change of category.

```
{
  "name": "",
  "category": "SMS",
  "description": "",
  "apiUrl": "",
  "apiMethod": "GET",
  "apiPayload": {
    "senderName": "",
    "number": "",
    "message": ""
  },
  "@class": "action"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `apiPayload` out of the `reduce` callback function.
And assign the value after the `reduce loop`.

```
$('#saveActions').on('click', function(e) {

    var apiPayload = {};

    var jsonData = $('form.form-horizontal#events')
        .find(':input:not(button):not(#new-option-event)').get()
        .reduce(function(acc, ele) {
            if (ele.closest('.payload')) {
            var i = 0;
            apiPayload[ele.name] = ele.value.trim();
        } else {
            acc[ele.name] = ele.value.trim();
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
    jsonData['apiPayload'] = apiPayload;//assign value
    jsonData['@class'] = "action";

    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4));
});
```